# \documentclass{exam} Problem: Text alignment problem

Tags: header-footer, exam, pagestyle

Thank you Tex-stackers for reviewing this post!

The problematic `\style{header}` command has been removed since I really just needed a title for my math worksheet.

However, there's still a problem with the first text line being indented in comparison to the 2nd text line.

So that's the problem I'd like to fix.

**mwe**

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     
          }
% ------------ DOCUMENT STARTS HERE---------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\textbf{Algebra II: Solving Equations by Completing the Square
\\ \\
Assignment 8A-3}
\bigskip
Solve each equation by completing the square.

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $k^2-12k+32&=0$
\\\\
$(b/2)^2 =(-12/2)^2=36$
\\\\
$(k^2-12k+36)-32+36&=0$
\\\\
$(k-6)(k-6)+4&=0$
\\\\
$(k-6)^2+4=0$\\
\vspace{4cm}

% Prob #2
\task $p^2-6p-55=0$

\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We can't compile your MWE as given. It must start with `\documentclass...` and end with `\end{document}`. There may be all sorts of other problems with it.

Comment: Even if I use `\documentclass{exam}` (from the question title), I get errors that I can't make sense of: it can't understand the `\settasks`, or it thinks `\begin{document}` isn't `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @PeterWilson @Teepeemm  REVISED code now posted above. This is so weird...no matter how many times I copy/pasted my complete MWE code from overleaf.com, the first line (i.e. ```\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}```) always fails to paste. The complete code does compile in overleaf. Very sorry for the omitted line of code in my OP. Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath You have not edited what you have posted.  If I put what you have into Overleaf, it complains that there isn't a `\begin{document}` when it gets to your `\settasks` command.

Comment: @Teepeemm  I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I try to copy paste the revised code into my OP. So should I just start over and post a new question? Could chrome os be causing the causing the copy/paste problem?

Comment: It looks like you haven't clicked [edit].  Do you still have the problem if you take out the `\settasks` command?  What is `\header` supposed to be doing?  Where is it defined?  You seem to have the wrong syntax for that command.

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks for your patience with my inept use of the edit button. Problem I discovered is that ``` must be on separate line from the first line of code. So mwe is now correct. I eliminated the troublesome header command. Now there's just an alignment problem with 1st 2 lines of text.

Comment: Are you not clicking "Save Edits"?  If you look at other Stack posts, you'll see "edited ..." next to the asker's name.  Yours doesn't have that, and hasn't changed since your first posting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142570/discussion-between-siuslaw-math-and-teepeemm).

Comment: Does adding `\noindent` before `\textbf` solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most document classes in LaTeX, the first line in a paragraph is indented by default to distinct between consecutive paragraphs. The indent length is determined by a length called `\parindent`.

If you want to suppress the the indentation in a specific paragraph, you can prepend its first line with `\noindent`, thus replacing the line  `\textbf{Algebra II: Solving Equations by Completing the Square` with `\noindent\textbf{Algebra II: Solving Equations by Completing the Square` should solve your problem.

If you want to cancel the indentation  in general, you can write in the preamble  `\stelength\parindent{0pt}`, but, in this case you should add some vertical space at the end of a paragraph so your text won't end up looking like a big rectangle. You can do that by changing the skip `\parskip`, something like `\setlength\parskip{\smallskipamount}` could be reasonable, but it is up to you.